# What's the advantage of buckets.Dictionary over using an array?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, collections, typescript

For javascript there is [buckets](https://github.com/mauriciosantos/buckets) and for typescript [typescript-collections](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections). For a lot of the classes I see the advantage. But what is the advantage of using the Dictionary class over javascript associative arrays?

I'm not trying to denigrate either library, just to understand the difference so I will better understand javascript.

Comment: Honestly -- I'd say this is just an opinion question. My feeling is that the basic classes like `Dictionary` are there for comfort and not necessary. A few helper functions may be useful, but beyond that, for an associative array in particular, I'd just use it directly. There are others like Stack/Queue/Linked List, that fit better in a platform where that functionality isn't readily accessible already elsewhere in the platform (even if it's not with the same name). JavaScript can do these without wrappers. I'd strongly suggest looking at the code and deciding for your self.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I think your saying it's opinion is an answer - that there is no difference other than preference of API.

Comment: I marked this to be held as it really is just an opinion question that really can't have a "right answer" other than to say there isn't a right answer. Some developers really like super rich object models, classes, etc., others don't. :)

Comment: @WiredPrairie I intended it a bit different. The collections.LinkedList adds functionality you can't get from just an array. My question was - does Dictionary add functionality, or just provide the same functionality differently. But I can see how it could be read as which approach do you prefer.

Comment: I'm a firm believer in diving into code like that and learning how it works. That's the great part about having access to the source code. I'm also cautious about using libraries that mirror other platforms as they may not be necessary, and may not be the best way to do something on the newer platform.

Answer (score 2):

On the whole, when people use many languages they like to transfer patterns between those languages. It is a judgement call as to whether this is a good or bad thing - in many cases the feature being ported to the language comes from another paradigm and may actually grate with the language concepts it is being transferred to.

In bad cases, the transfer disrespects the target language (i.e. there are better ways to achieve the same result without writing unnecessary classes). In the worst cases, the transfer disrespects the source language. I have seen several attempts to transfer C# Linq extensions to JavaScript that all process Linq query immediately and store the results in a second array - one of the benefits of Linq is that it will process the query when the result is enumerated, which allows more data to be processed than can be stored in memory (as one example).

I have ported features before, mostly for fun because it is an interesting learning experience (for example, I wrote a [Linq example to demonstrate the problem with other Linq examples that were being posted](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201403/Blog/Real-Linq-Style-Operations-Using-ECMAScript-6/)).

If a feature or pattern is being transferred to make the target language more familiar, it is probably being done for the wrong reason.

If it is being transferred because it adds a feature that is needed that is inspired by a good pattern from another language, that is fine. The acid test for this is whether it saves you from repeating boilerplate code, for example checking what is in an existing array before adding to it.